# Аналог vhosts для Docker Apache2+PHP

Tags: docker, apache2

Без Docker я создавал несколько virtualhost'ов, и к каждому привязывал свою версию PHP по надобности, и заходил на сайты по доменам sitename1.dev, sitename2.dev.

А как поступить с Docker? Есть у меня два PHP+Apache2 контейнера, как их запустить одновременно на одном порте и привязать домены (на локалхосте)?

Comment: запустить перед ними прокси (например nginx), который будет на основании домена перенаправлять трафик в нужный контейнер

Comment: а как привязывать прокси к контейнерам? делать уровнем выше над всем этим dokcer-compose?

Comment: да, запустить `nginx` как отдельный контейнер или прямо на хосте, т.к. ваши приложение в любом случае выставляют какой-то порт (например 5001, 5002) вот на него и перенаправилять